# react-native build error: FAILURE: Build failed with an exception

Tags: react-native, kotlin, error-handling, react-native-cli

I am very new to nativescript, i try to build my first app in nativescript, but it shows
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'E:\workplace\last\node_modules@react-native\gradle-plugin\build.gradle.kts' line: 13
- What went wrong:
  Plugin [id: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm', version: '1.7.22'] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm:org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm.gradle.plugin:1.7.22')
  Searched in the following repositories:
  MavenRepo
  Google
  Gradle Central Plugin Repository

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDP3L.png)
  it is my informatin.
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tvnvf.png)

run command `yarn android`